# Yii How to foreach data from DB

Tags: php, yii

How yii foreach data from DB ?  One developer have multiple game, but when i call the data out from DB it only show one data

Following is my coding :

**In Controller**

```
$id = Yii::app()->user->getState('id');
$thedb = GamesDevelopersApp::model()->find('developer_id='.$id);
$gametitle     = CHtml::encode($thedb->gametitle);
$version       = CHtml::encode($thedb->version);
$create_time   = CHtml::encode($thedb->uploaddate);
$status        = CHtml::encode($thedb->status);

$this->render('applist',array('gametitle'=>$gametitle,'version'=>$version,'create_time'=>$create_time,'status'=>$status));
```

**In HTML**

```
    <td class="apptd2">
        <?php foreach($models as $model){
            echo CHTML::encode($model->gametitle);  
        }; ?>
    </td>
```

Comment: Your question is not clear.As per you if one developer have multiple game then there should be more than one row in result.SO you can do foreach with $thedb

Comment: is `gametitle` an relation?

Comment: @AbhisekMalakar yes it should be more than one row in result ... foreach `$thedb` ? do you have example ? so i can try understand

Comment: @Dinistro `gametitle` is column name in DB ...

Comment: Then it should be `foreach($results AS $result) { echo $result['gametitle']; }` (pseudo code).

Comment: @Paul undefined results

Comment: This was just pseudo-code, you need to use your variables, e.g. `$thedb`. I was just saying, if `gametitle` is a column, you can't do a `foreach` on that but you need to loop through your results.

Comment: @Paul so what should i do to foreach the data ? please help ... im confusing

Comment: Yes, you are confusing. ;) This might work (which Yii version you are working with?): `foreach($thedb AS $result) { echo $result['gametitle']; }`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/64157/discussion-between-the-smile-and-paul).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your DB request you are just retrieving one entry because you are using the `find` method:

```
$thedb = GamesDevelopersApp::model()->find('developer_id='.$id);
```

And in the Yii doc you'll see fot he `find` method:

> Finds a single active record with the specified condition.

This is why the following loop has no sense

```
<?php foreach($gametitle as $title){
   echo $title;  
 }; ?>
```

For me the best would be to use `findAll` in the controller:

```
$id = Yii::app()->user->getState('id');
$models = GamesDevelopersApp::model()->findAll('developer_id='.$id);
$this->render('applist',array('models'=>$models));
```

And the following loop in the view:

```
<?php foreach($models as $model){
   echo CHTML::encode($model->gametitle);  
 }; ?>
```

Comment: thanks for the reply but the output error is `Trying to get property of non-object `

Comment: @darkheir, you said you want to use `findAll`, but you're using `find`.

Comment: My bad, it's the morning in my country ^^

Comment: @darkheir: I know this^^. I think that it should work now.

Comment: HIHI `findAll` is worked ! but suddenly come out another problem ... see my updated question

Comment: with a table, a list, etc...

Comment: @Dinistro meaning ?im doing wrong ?

Comment: It means it depends how you want to display the data. You could use an html table, an html list, juste go to the next line, ...